# How to write a value in PostgreSQL that will change depending on context?

Tags: postgresql

I am building a relational DB in PostgreSQL. Here are the relevant parts of the schema:

```
-- enums
CREATE TYPE "timeframe" AS ENUM (
  ...
);

CREATE TYPE "object_type" AS ENUM (
  ...
);

-- tables
CREATE TABLE "inventory" (
  "inventory_id" uuid UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE "character" (
  "character_id" uuid UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "max_base_position" integer NOT NULL,
  "current_position" integer NOT NULL,
  "inventory" uuid UNIQUE NOT NULL references inventory(inventory_id),
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE "consumable" (
  "consumable_id" uuid UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE "effect" (
  "effect_id" uuid UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  "description" varchar(4096),
  "position_cost" integer,
  "duration_timeframe" timeframe NOT NULL,
  "duration_amount" integer,
  "object_type_affected" object_type NOT NULL,
  "field_affected" varchar(64),
  "operation" operation,
  "magnitude" integer,
  "active" bool NOT NULL
);

-- join tables
CREATE TABLE "consumable_effect" (
  "consumable" uuid NOT NULL references consumable(consumable_id),
  "effect" uuid NOT NULL references effect(effect_id),
  PRIMARY KEY ("consumable", "effect")
);

CREATE TABLE "inventory_consumables" (
  "inventory" uuid NOT NULL references inventory(inventory_id),
  "consumable" uuid NOT NULL references consumable(consumable_id),
  PRIMARY KEY ("inventory", "consumable")
);

-- test data
insert into effect values
    (gen_random_uuid(), 'Restore half of base Position', null, 0, 'instantaneous', 0, 'character', 'current_position', '+', [something goes here], true)
    returning *;
```

So, to summarize, we have characters that have one inventory each. These inventories can have consumables, and that relationship is modeled by a join table. One of these consumables has an effect that, upon use, adds half of the character's max_base_position to its current_position. What I'm trying to do is put something in [something goes here] that will produce a value equal to half of the max_base_position of the character using the consumable. The problem is that this value needs to change depending on the character using the consumable. I'm fine with adding some magic to my API or frontend, or even modifying the schema, to facilitate this. This project is still in the design/document stage, so nothing is nailed down yet.

My initial thought was to try and do like, a bunch of nested subqueries to get to the character's max_base_position, but I got a quarter of the way through and decided not to since it was becoming a huge hassle and I realized it wouldn't be a solution anyway. A colleague recommended using a stored procedure, but I'm not very well versed in PostgreSQL to begin with, so that didn't pan out for me on my own.

**Update for additional context**: The application is an interactive character sheet for a TTRPG. So the effects would only need to affect the stats currently present on the screen. For example, the application flow for the consumable from my example above would be: user clicks "Use" next to the consumable's name in the inventory of their character sheet -> the current position of the character goes up by half of their base position rounded down, to a max of their max base position -> consumable disappears from the character's inventory. There currently is no application code for this since the project is still being designed. Additionally, the database hasn't actually been created yet, I'm just crafting the schema right now. On top of this, there is already a wealth of information (e.g. consumables with effects, armors and shields with special effects, origins with bloodied effects, class features with effects) to design the DB schema off of. I'm simply trying to create a framework for storing that info and allowing users to create new custom ones as well. As such, hardcoding each effect would not only be laborious to start with, but impossible going forward. I need these effects to be generic in the sense that I could apply an effect to any compatible item (i.e. any passive effect should be applicable to any equippable item and any activatable effect should be applicable to any item), and I need the effect storage to be extensible.

Comment: I doubt this is possible to represent completely in the database. You have `object_type_affected`, `field_affected`, `operation`, `magnitude`, but there will be lots of effects that are more than just that. So don't bother storing them in the database. These should live in the application code, in the business logic, as individual objects/procedures. All you need to store is an identifier for the implementation. Only later, when you find that you have many (groups of) similar effects that should be parameterised, it makes sense to store the parameters in the database.

Comment: What you want sounds like a query that joins two tables, or a view based on such a query. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Bergi could you elaborate some more on your comment? What is it that you mean by "an identifier for the implementation"? The project this is for is a personal one that is intended to teach me new things, and, as such, this is my first time writing a DB schema. I apologize if I'm asking something that ought to be apparent.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you for your comment, I will look into joins and views.

Comment: It looks like you are writing a game. What does the application code look like? Can you show the part that applies the effects? Those are objects initialised from the database, right? I mean that you should create the effects with their business logic as hardcoded objects (with an `apply()` method) in your application, and when it comes to loading them from the database (or storing them into the database), give each object a unique identifier nothing more.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated the question with some additional context to address your questions and comments.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. You either code your application so that `if (effect.name == 'Restore half of base Position') magnitude = character.max_base_position / 2` (and do that for every kind of effect that needs special magnitude handling), or you change the `magnitude` field from the `int`eger to something that can represent complex formulas (which your application can then evaluate). It really depends on how special effect behaviours you have. Depending on the complexity of the rulebook, you may need a scripting language for this…